# Compare Python class to None with is operator

Tags: python, oop, singleton, comparison, nonetype

Is there a way to compare a Python class to None using the `is` operator?

```
class DefaultValue:
    def __init__(self, default, value=None):
        self.default = default
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value or self.default)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

d = DefaultValue(False)

str(d) # 'False' 

d == None # True 

d is None # False
```

Is there something I can implement on the class so that the **is** operator will return **True** when comparing to **None**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overload the `is` operator because it is used to check if two variables refer to the same value, which you should never need to overload. The most similar thing is to overload `==` with the `__eq__` method:

```
class MyClass:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        #code here
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Following similar syntax of the other operator overrides methods you have defined, you can do one for is_. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think that is available to implement on the class itself, right? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html